# Why doesn't the A-4 Skyhawk require rudder in coordinated turns like on other Century Series aircraft?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-controls, rudder, coordinated-flight, douglas-a-4-skyhawk

The [Douglas A-4 Skyhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_A-4_Skyhawk) is a subsonic jet aircraft design from the early fifties.

Usually, in order to make a coordinate turn without skidding or slipping , the  pilots of the other types of aircrafts must move the rudder to the side where they want to turn  alongside with the ailerons and elevators.
However, the A-4 does not require any rudder movements . Use of the rudder is allowed only in cross winds at landing according to a navy pilot writing on a [message board](https://rnzaf.proboards.com/thread/2032/skyhawk-rudder):

> An every day use would be during takeoff and landing in a crosswind to control the strong tendency for the A4 with the large tail fin to point its nose into the cross wind. This could be disastrous if not brought under control with the large rudder being very effective at slow airspeeds. And of course the spoilers dumping lift on landing so that aircraft weight went on to the main wheels for more effective braking and less tendency to weathercock.
>
> In my day learning to fly with the RAAF - before rejoining the Navy (FAA) - we learnt to fly on Winjeels where all kinds of spins were allowed and practiced. In the Vampire NO. Spins were forbidden - this is where we learnt the 'feet on floor' technique. In the Sea Venom it was a similar situation but by this time we were also flying Vampires in the Navy (1969-70) the technique was ingrained to not use rudders in flight and now not in the Skyhawk.

Is it because of the shape of the wings or the rudder position?

Comment: Where’s the question? You seem to have answered your own.

Comment: Also, where's your source for the statement that rudder is prohibited?

Comment: I can't find the information on the Skyhawk, but it's almost certainly because the airplane has a yaw damper which takes care of minor yaw excursions.  You don't apply rudder for maneuvering if you have a yaw damper, because it messes up the damper's act.

Comment: I have a TA-4J NATOPS manual at home I could check later, but I don't remember such a restriction, and agree with John K that it probably wasn't needed due to the yaw damper.  And as GdD said, if you are going to base a question on an assertion you should at least try to substantiate the truth of it.  I didn't read the entire Wikipedia page, did it come from there?

Comment: VTC as "Needs details or clarity" - specifically, support for the "is prohibited" statement.

Comment: I checked the NATOPS, no mention of using or not using rudder.  If you care to edit the question for clarity I would be happy to provide a better answer for the record.  The question isn't even clear, e.g:  "...pilot had to push the pedal..." and "...does not require any rudder..." contradict each other.  Which one do you think it is, and why?!

Comment: https://youtu.be/2eah13pmp9Y in this  you tube interview pilot said that.

Comment: @GeorgeGeo I edited the question a bit for clarity, please provide the time on the video when the pilot states the rudder is prohibited item in turns. Just for ease, the interview is very interesting, but more than an hour long 

Comment: One would see similarities in these procedures and other jet aircraft:  to avoid overstressing the tail at higher airspeeds.  Instead of an aggressive push on the rudder, which could produce a drastic and sudden increase in force on the tail (and hanging ordinance) in a skid, perhaps better to err on the side of slip (a more gentle lateral acceleration), and let the natural shape of the delta wing and tail help it through the turn.

Comment: Probably less about overstressing the tail and more about avoiding a nasty abrupt departure from controlled flight.  ("Maneuvering" in this context probably means loaded up at high G in a fight...)  George, help us help you by providing a timestamp.  I don't have the time or interest to listen to the entire podcast, but the context around his remark is important.  While I wasn't a Viet Nam A-4 pilot, my 114 hours in the two seat training version gives me some perspective, and might be just enough to provide a useful answer if I can understand what he is referring to.

Comment: Michael Hall, yes "probably less about overstressing the tail and more about avoiding a nasty abrupt departure from controlled flight" In simulation this is happening with rudder deflection.But I don't know why. This was the reason why I asked here.

Comment: My opinion is the length of the rudder (not all tail) when deflected.

Comment: George, please add a timestamp for the comment: At which hr:mn:sec of the YouTube video one can find the relevant comment? As Michael said, help him help you – you have a unique opportunity to get an answer to you question.

Comment: If you are asking how well your simulator emulates the actual flight characteristics of the A-4, that is a different question.  But in almost any airplane, if you are loaded with Gs and stomp on the rudder things will go poorly.  In case you wonder why this is happening...

Comment: Part of me wants to try to answer this, but the question is still a bit messy...  First, pilot technique is not at all the same as a prohibited maneuver.  And second, has it been established that the A-4 is substantially different from other centerline thrust swept wing jets of the era in terms of rudder use?  Most fighters don't need a lot of rudder.  And does the quote match what is said in the video that still doesn't have a time stamp listed for the remark?  It seems that others care more about the question than the OP, and it has morphed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the included quote, this probably because of the effectiveness of rudder control on the A-4.  If it's effective enough at low speed to control against a high crosswind component for takeoff or landing, it's *way too much* when at operational speed.

That is to say, if the pilot were to apply proverse rudder in a common turn, he'd push the airplane into a skid by overpowering the applied bank.  The required deflection to coordinate the turn would be so small as to be nearly impossible to apply -- and the A-4 is too old to have computer-managed controls that give more authority at low airspeed and less when fast.  Hence, once clear of the ground, clean, and up to normal operational speed, feet flat on the floor is the order of the day.

Comment: Zeis Ikon, but  for small deflection couldn't  pilot use the rudder trim knob?

Comment: Not something you'd normally do during a turn (a few seconds to a couple minutes).  Trim is what you'd use, for instance, if under-wing stores on one wing were gone, to counter asymmetric drag.